# mutating method sent to immutable object

Tags: ios, iphone

Mutating method sent to immutable object.

Here following are my code:

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView commitEditingStyle:(UITableViewCellEditingStyle)editingStyle forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    NSString *strNameEmp = [[NSString alloc]init];

    if (newContactFound == 2 ) {



        strEntered = [phoneArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
        strNameEmp = [availPointsArr objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

        int IdIndex   = [arrEmpIds indexOfObject:strEntered];
        int nameIndex = [arrEmpName indexOfObject:strNameEmp];




        [arrEmpIds removeObjectAtIndex:IdIndex];
        [arrEmpName removeObjectAtIndex:nameIndex];
```

Answer (score 0):

Make sure first that array which you are using its mutable array. and second thing while You are getting array from somewhere use syntax mutable copy.

```
  mutableArray = [[data valueForKey:@"key"] mutableCopy];
```